# Are there continuous bijective functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology that are not open functions?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Both domain and codomain with the standard topology, I can't imagine any example, could somebody give me one if it exists?

I apologize if this was asked before, I didn't found it. In any case if this was already asked i will delete this post
Thanks

Comment: Here is a more interesting question.  Suppose $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ is continuous and bijective.  Must it be a homeomorphism?

Comment: @GEdgar I doubt it...?

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, by invariance of domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sequence of hints.

A continuous bijection $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing (hint: intermediate value theorem).

Without loss of generality we can assume $f$ to be strictly increasing. The inverse function is therefore continuous as well, because an increasing function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ can only have jump discontinuities, but bijectivity excludes them.

Hence $f$ is a homeomorphism and so it is open and closed.